# export from module

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

Here is a code taken from http://www.angelfire.com/tx4/cus/shapes/haskell98.html .
It compiles and executes correctly in WinGHCi if I comment the names in the module header. But if the names are kept then it does not compile - it reports an error on the name MakeCircle. My question is: if I want to explicitly mention that I want to export MakeCircle, what code changes are required?

```
module Circle -- (Circle, MakeCircle, getRadius, setRadius)
  where
  import Shape

  class Shape a => Circle a where
      getRadius :: a -> Int
      setRadius :: a -> Int -> a

  instance Shape CircleInstance where
      getX = x
      getY = y
      setX a newx = a {x = newx}
      setY a newy = a {y = newy}
      moveTo a newx newy = a {x = newx, y = newy}
      rMoveTo a deltax deltay = a {x = ((getX a) + deltax), y = ((getY a) + deltay)}
      draw a =
         putStrLn ("Drawing a Circle at:(" ++ (show (getX a)) ++ "," ++ (show (getY a)) ++
            "), radius " ++ (show (getRadius a)))

   instance Circle CircleInstance where
      getRadius = radius
      setRadius a newradius = a {radius = newradius}

   data CircleInstance = MakeCircle {x, y, radius :: Int}
      deriving(Eq, Show)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`MakeCircle` is a *data constructor* for the type `CircleInstance`.  Data constructors can only be exported in combination with their defining type.  You will probably also want to export the `Circle` class methods `getRadius` and `setRadius`; with the current export list those methods will be unavailable outside this module.

Change your export list to

```
module Circle (Circle (..), CircleInstance (MakeCircle), getRadius, setRadius)
```

This shows two forms of exporting.  The export `Circle (..)` exports the type class `Circle` and all of its methods, while `CircleInstance (MakeCircle)` exports the type constructor `CircleInstance` and only its data constructor `MakeCircle`.  If you were to add a new data constructor for MakeCircle, perhaps a `UnitCircle`, that constructor wouldn't be exported from the module unless you either mention it in the export list (i.e. `CircleInstance (MakeCircle, UnitCircle)` ) or use the `(..)` form of exports.

Answer (score 5):

The export list is incorrect, it should be:

```
module Circle(Circle, CircleInstance(MakeCircle), getRadius, setRadius)
```

Or perhaps

```
module Circle(Circle, CircleInstance(..), getRadius, setRadius)
```